# Сессия пропадает после редиректа на поддомен

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Отправляю ajax-запросом данные:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/engine/search.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        data:data
    },
    xhrFields: { 
        withCredentials: true
    },
    success: function(){
        console.log('Request sent successfully. Pending...')
    }
}).fail(function(response){
    console.log(response);
}).done(function(data){
    console.log('Validation passed, initiating redirect...');
    window.location.href = 'https://search.' + document.location.hostname;
});
```

К скрипту:

```
<?php 
ini_set('session.cookie_domain',  '.skytickets.ga');
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.skytickets.ga');
session_start();
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
require('functions.php');
if(isAjax()) {
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    if(isset($data) && !empty($data)) {
        if(!preg_match('/[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]/', $data['from']) && !preg_match('/[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]/', $data['to'])) {
            header('HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error');
            die('Bad IATA codes provided');
        }
        if(!validateDate($data['there']) && !validateDate($data['thence'])) {
            header('HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error');
            die('Bad date format provided');
        }
        if(!preg_match('/^[1-9]*$/', $data['adults']) && !preg_match('/^[0-9]*$/', $data['teens']) && !preg_match('/^[0-9]*$/', $data['kids'])) {
            header('HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error');
            die('Bad passengers data provided');
        }
        $_SESSION['search_data'] = json_encode($data);
        session_write_close();
    }
} else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    die('Access denied');
}
?>
```

После успешной обработки запроса в теле `.done()` на клиенте происходит перемещение на поддомен, в котором должен производиться вывод данных:

```
<?php 
session_start();
require('../engine/functions.php');
require('../engine/headers.php');

if(isset($_SESSION['search_data']) && !empty($_SESSION['search_data']))
    var_dump($_SESSION['search_data']);
unset($_SESSION['search_data']);
?>
```

Но вместо вывода ничего не происходит, а если убрать условный оператор, то будет выведен `Notice: undefined index 'search_data'`, а var_dump() выведет NULL. Чего я только не пробовал, всё никак не хочет работать.

Answer (score 1):

```
session_set_cookie_params();
```

ru2.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

И вот тут дали хороший ответ:

stackoverflow.com/questions/644920/allow-php-sessions-to-carry-over-to-subdomains